# ASP.NET MVC2 validation not working with drop down list in IE <8

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a form with a dropdownlist rendered using `Html.DropDownListFor(...)`. The view model field that corresponds with the dropdown list has a `[Required(...)]` attribute attached to it. This works fine on my local machine, but as soon as I publish to our development server, the drop down lists keep displaying the required error message, even when a value is selected in the list. This only happens in IE - Firefox submits just fine.

Any thoughts?

**Relevant code**

View:

```
<ol class="form">
    <li>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContactTitle) %>
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.ContactTitle, Model.GetTitleOptions()) %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ContactTitle) %>
    </li>
    <!-- more fields... -->
</ol>
```

View Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
[DisplayName("Title")]
public string ContactTitle { get; set; }

// ...

public SelectList GetTitleOptions()
{
    return new SelectList(new string[] 
    {
        "","Dr.", "Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs.", "Miss"
    });
}
```

It's all pretty basic stuff... I'm at a loss.

Edit: Just discovered this bug is limited to IE 8 compatibility view (and maybe prior versions). IE 8 in standards mode works as expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chalk this one up to stupidity. The code in the example produces output similar to the following:

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option>Dr.</option>
    <option>Mr.</option>
    <option>Ms.</option>
    <option>Mrs.</option>
    <option>Miss</option>
</select>
```

And the relevant MVC validation function (when a RequiredAttribute is applied to a property that corresponds to a drop down list) is:

```
Sys.Mvc.RequiredValidator._validateSelectInput = function Sys_Mvc_RequiredValidator$_validateSelectInput(optionElements) {
    /// <param name="optionElements" type="DOMElementCollection">
    /// </param>
    /// <returns type="Object"></returns>
    for (var i = 0; i < optionElements.length; i++) {
        var element = optionElements[i];
        if (element.selected) {
            if (!Sys.Mvc._validationUtil.stringIsNullOrEmpty(element.value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Notice the function checks `element.value`. In the case of the html above, the `value` attribute is empty because there is no value attribute on the option elements. Therefore, the validation function returns false and the error occurs. This only appears to happen in IE <8, presumably because other browsers by default assign an option element's text to the value attribute if none is specified.

The solution was to modify the way I was returning the select list items from which the drop down list was built like so:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetTitleOptions()
{
    return BuildSelectListItems(new string[] 
    {
        "","Dr.", "Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs.", "Miss"
    });
}

private List<SelectListItem> BuildSelectListItems(IEnumerable<string> values) {
    return (from v in values
            select new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = v,
                Value = v
            }).ToList();
}
```

This results in the much more predictable HTML output:

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
</select>
```

which of course the function validates properly.